# Рекурсия вызваная из базового класса

Tags: c++, классы, функции, рекурсия

Все мы знаем обычную рекурсию, например:

```
функция имя(){
    условие_завершения;
    имя();
}
```

Понятно что эта функция будет существовать в памяти в нескольких экземплярах до завершения всей цепочки вызовов.

Встретил вот такой код:

```
class SimpleDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
public:
    void paint(QPainter*                   pPainter,
               const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
               const QModelIndex&          index
              ) const
......
условие_выхода
......
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(pPainter, option, index); // рекурсия ?
    }
};
```

Вроде бы тоже рекурсия но как она работает? То ли копия базового объекта создается то ли просто метод дублируется для текущего объекта, то ли.. , в общем не понятно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данном определении функции-члена класса рекурсии нет

```
class SimpleDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
public:
    void paint(QPainter*                   pPainter,
               const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
               const QModelIndex&          index
              ) const
......
условие_выхода
......
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(pPainter, option, index); // рекурсия ?
    }
};
```

Имеются две различные функции. Одна функция - это `SimpleDelegate::paint` , другая функция  - это `QStyledItemDelegate::paint`.

Первая функция в области определения производного класса скрывает объявление второй функции с тем же самым именем в базовом классе. Поэтому если вы хотите из функции производного класса вызвать одноименную функцию базового класса, то вам нужно указывать ее квалифицированное имя, что и делается в приведенном примере.

Рассмотрите данную демонстрационную программу

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    struct A
    {
        void f(const char *) const { std::cout << "Hello"; }
        void f(char) const { std::cout << ' '; }
    };

    struct B : A
    {
        void f(const std::string &s ) const
        { 
            A::f(nullptr);
            A::f(' ');
            std::cout << s << std::endl;
        }
    };

    B().f(std::string("perfect"));

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
Hello perfect
```

Здесь функция, объявленная в производном классе `B` скрывает одноименные функции, объявленные в базовом классе `A`. Поэтому чтобы обратиться к этим функциям базового класса в области определения производного класса, следует использовать квалифицированные имена функций базового класса.

Другой альтернативный подход при условии, что нет неоднозначности в перегрузке функций, это использовать `using` объявления в производном классе. Например,

```
struct B : A
{
    using A::f;
    void f(const std::string &s ) const
    { 
        f(nullptr);
        f(' ');
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Однако, если сигнатуры одноименных функций в базовом и производном классах совпадают, то, чтобы исключить неоднозначность, придется явно указывать квалифицированные имена функций для базового класса.

Comment: Спасибо, пока ехал домой уже это осознал самостоятельно. ) Просто спешил перед уходом домой. А вот про использование using для обращения к родителю не знал, собственно за что и спасибо, приятно видеть такие подробное ответы )

Comment: @perfect Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Answer (score 2):

`QStyledItemDelegate::paint(pPainter, option, index);` вызовет метод `paint` у класса QStyledItemDelegate, который является базовым, относительно `SimpleDelegate`. Это не является рекурсивным вызовом.

> Понятно что эта функция будет существовать в памяти в нескольких
>   экземплярах

у функций нет экземпляров.

Comment: если мы имеем несколько одинаковых штук чего то, то это экземпляры. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80 плюс вот это вам очень пригодится https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: @perfect вам пригодится почаще заглядывать в отладчик.